# Prevent jQuery() from executing javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on some code that uses jQuery to parse data out of html documents from the web.  This decision was made because jQuery, with its awesome ability to select objects on a page, makes it excellent for parsing.

The code works like this (where 'html_string' is the html of a whole web page):

```
var page = $(html_string);
```

The problem I am having is that javascript is being evaluated and executed within the html_string as well.  This results in new threads being formed that in some cases, contain infinite loops that make repeated requests to the server and eventually crash the whole  client-side of application (not the server).

Is there a way to somehow prevent the execution of javascript in this situation.  In this situation, the execution of javascript is an unwanted side effect.

Thanks so much!

Comment: This line of code will not execute any scripts. Your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: how are you pulling the html?

Comment: (Adding to @GolezTrol's comment; you can see this by comparing http://jsfiddle.net/UbCFc/ to http://jsfiddle.net/UbCFc/1)

Comment: lol, that fiddle was so much more concise than mine..

Comment: GolezTrol is right up to a point, and if it in fact is a string, why bother with jQuery selector? Just assign the string as string,  `var page = html_string;` otherwise jQuery will definitely execute selector functions trying to find object that would match string as selector. But there is no return or infin. loop that would crash your page.

Comment: @Tumharyyaaden It has its use to JQueryfy the string. It allows you to parse the html and find individual nodes, just as you can in your normal document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a crappy little jsfiddle that shows you the js does not run when you load the html_string into $. When you click run you will see an immediate alert 'wtf'.  Three seconds later, the html is loaded into $ and the body is updated to say 'moo', you should not see the alert.

http://jsfiddle.net/9BAkE/

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, but it does show that the question is wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to parse the html string befor you wrap it with jQuery.

Something like:

```
var page = html_string;


//then find the script tag (untested code)
int beginning_of_script = page.indexOf('<script>');
int end_of_script = page.indexOf('</script>');

// remove the script
page = page.remove(beginning_of_script, end_of_script);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could load this syntax into the browser initially as a comment

```
<script>
/* var page = $(html_string); */
</script>
```

and then extract the contents of the comment later. The advantage here is that the browser is not going to parse and execute the comment on page load.

You can also explore using jQuery's [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function, not sure if that will suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you donot care having one extra element, check this! http://jsfiddle.net/UbCFc/4/